# How to delete all referential tables in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, foreign-keys

I have table test0. This table referenced by tables:

```
test1
test2
test3
....
test150
```

Does it possible write simple short query to delete 1 row in table test0 and if they exist - in all tables test1 ... test150 ?

Comment: I cannot change table to use cascade delete.

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You get the foreign keys from all_constraints and construct queries to do it from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this function to get delete script for all of the child rows of the given parent row:

```
Create or replace
FUNCTION FN_GET_DELETE_SCRIPT
( Parent_ID IN VARCHAR2, Parent_Table_Name in varchar2   
) RETURN varchar2
AS 
sql_statement varchar2(200);
script varchar2(4000);
n pls_integer;
Tot Pls_Integer := 0;
Cc_Id Varchar2(500):=Null;
Cursor allTables 
Is    
   Select uc.table_name , ac.column_name
   from user_constraints uc , ALL_CONS_COLUMNS AC
   Where 
      R_Constraint_Name = (Select Constraint_Name  From User_Constraints Where Constraint_Type = 'P' And Table_Name = upper(Parent_Table_Name))
      And Ac.Owner = Uc.Owner
      And AC.constraint_name = uc.constraint_name;
Begin   
   for t in allTables loop
    execute immediate 'select count(*) from '||t.table_name ||' where '||t.column_name||' = :1' into n using Parent_ID;    
     If N > 0 Then    
        script:='Delete From ' ||t.table_name||' Where '||t.column_name||'='''||Parent_ID||''';'||chr(10)||script;
    End if; 
    End loop;
  Return Script;
END FN_GET_DELETE_SCRIPT;
```

Note that this function gives you a delete script for deleting immediate children of the given parent row.
So this function needs a bit of modification to find all descendants of the given parent rows!

Answer (score 1):

- Try like this

  ```
   CREATE TABLE supplier 
   ( supplier_id numeric(10) not null, 
   supplier_name varchar2(50) not null, 
   contact_name varchar2(50),  
   CONSTRAINT supplier_pk PRIMARY KEY (supplier_id) 
   ); 



  CREATE TABLE products 
  (product_id numeric(10) not null, 
  supplier_id numeric(10) not null, 
  CONSTRAINT fk_supplier 
  FOREIGN KEY (supplier_id) 
  REFERENCES supplier(supplier_id) 
  ON DELETE CASCADE 
  );
  ```
- According to your requirement first drop all constraints and recreate them using on delete cascade as shown in above axample
- Delete the supplier, and it will delate all products for that supplier
- but be careful while using on delete cascade "You can, by mistake, delete half of your database without even realizing it"

Answer (score 0):

You can do:
 alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name; and then add new constraint with on delete cascade.